# Bash: Brace expansion in scripts not working due to unwanted escaping

Tags: bash, escaping, brace-expansion

I want to do something like this in a bash script. I'm using `bash 4.1.10`.

```
# rm -rf /some/path/{folder1,folder2,folder3}
```

Works nicely (and as expected) from the shell itself. It deletes the 3 desired folders leaving all others untouched.

When I put it into script something unwanted happens. For example, my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
VAR="folder1,folder2,folder3"
rm -rf /some/path/{$VAR}
```

When I execute this script, the folders are not deleted.

I think this is due to the fact that some unwanted quoting is occurring. Output from the script using `#!/bin/bash -x`:

```
rm -rf '/some/path/{folder1,folder2,folder3}'
```

which of course cannot succeed due to the `'` marks.

How can I get this working within my script?

Comment: Do you absolutly want to use {}-expansion, or is an equivalent alternative ok?

Comment: sure.. I just have a list of subfolder names I want to remove in ONE concrete subshell in background -means more concrete: rm -rf /some/path/{folder1,folder2,folder3} & not a loop which runs over each subfolder doing this as this would increase fileserver load

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to [the man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash):

> The order of expansions is: brace expansion, tilde  expansion,  parameter,  variable  and arithmetic expansion and command substitution (done in a left-to-right fashion), word splitting, and pathname expansion.

So to get around this, add another level of expansion:

```
eval "rm -rf /some/path/{$VAR}"
```

Comment: How to get around brace expansion, though?

Comment: `function sort-note() { mv "$1"{,\;Sorted}; }`. Eg, like in maildir, but for my own purposes?

Comment: At command line: `mv foo.note{,\;Sorted}; ls foo.note* # foo.note;Sorted`

Answer (score 5):

Since you're writing a script, there's no reason to write hard-to-maintain code using `eval` tricks

```
VAR="f1,f2,f3"
IFS=,
set -- $VAR
for f; do
  rm -r "/path/to/$f"
done
```

or

```
VAR=( f1 f2 f3 )
for f in "${VAR[@]}"; do 
  rm -r "/path/to/$f"
done
```

Answer (score 2):

No, it's due to the fact that brace expansion happens before parameter expansion. Find another way of doing this, such as with `xargs`.

```
xargs -d , -I {} rm -rf /some/path/{} <<< "$VAR"
```

Answer (score 2):

If your code can be rearranged, you can use `echo` and command substitution in bash. 
Something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
VAR=`echo /some/path/{folder1,folder2,folder3}`
rm -rf $VAR
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable braceexpand flag:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -B
for i in /some/path/{folder1,folder2,folder3}
do
  rm -rf "$i"
done
```

Comment: DOesn't seem to work for me. (Note that the `"/some/path/{folder1,folder2,folder3}"` string is stored in a variable; if you enter the above literally in a shell it will work because the shell does the expansion, but it's of no use in a script.)

Comment: But if you know the actual literal list of things you want to do brace expansion of, then it would work: `for i in ${prefix}{fixed,list,of,literal,strings}${suffix}` would loop over 5 strings, with `${prefix}` and `${suffix}` properly substituted.

Comment: Fixed the answer. You need to set -B / braceexpand with set, or provide it as a bash parameter :)

Comment: No, still doesn't work. I don't think you understand the question: suppose you have a variable, like `VAR="/tmp/{folder1,folder2,folder3}"`. Now you want to create (say) the corresponding directories, using $VAR. How do you do it? (If you don't have it in a var and can just type it directly, then everything is fine, as I said in my second comment above.)

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
VAR="folder1,folder2,folder3"
eval "rm -rf /some/path/{$VAR}"
```

---

**Edit** The remainder is just for info. I try to be informative, but not wordy :_)

Recent bashes have the globstar option. This might perhaps come in handy in the future

```
shopt -s globstar
rm -rfvi some/**/folder?
```

Comment: i my concrete case I do not have folder1,folder2,folder3 but complete different names. Put for this special example this would have worked.

Comment: @Roland: I'm really mentioning `globstar` which I guess you didn't know yet. You did notice the answer (you know, the _first part_)?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not that *in script mode some unwanted quoting is happening* but that you put the folder names into a variable and the variable content is expanded *after* the brace expansion is done.
If you really want to do it like this you have to use `eval`:

```
eval "rm -rf /some/path/{$VAR}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Another trick you can use (instead of the dangerous `eval`) is just plain `echo` inside a subshell. This works, for instance:

```
paths=`echo /some/path/{folder1,folder2,folder3}`
echo rm -rf $paths
```

outputs:

```
rm -rf /some/path/folder1 /some/path/folder2 /some/path/folder3
```

as desired. (Remove the "echo" in the second line, to make it actually do the `rm`.)

---

The crucial point is that bash does brace expansion *before* parameter expansion, so you never want to put a comma-separated list (surrounded by braces or not) into a variable -- if you do, then you'll have to resort to `eval`. You can however put a list of space-separated strings into a variable, by having the brace expansion happen in a subshell *before* assignment.

Answer (score -1):

replace `{$VAR}` by `${VAR}` :-)

Comment: I want braces to be generated about the content of $VAR not brace expansion of $VAR